# Is it possible to generate a different column name for a property when generating SQL schema from the .edmx file?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-generation, ef-model-first

I've "inherited" an EF 4.0 `.edmx` file. Currently a given property name and column name are identical in the generated C# and SQL schema. I've since upgraded to EF 4.1, and changed the code generation item to generate a `DbContext` instead of an `ObjectContext`.

What I want to do is generate a SQL schema where the column names could be different. For example, say I have an `Id` property/column for `Product`; I want to generate `Id` for the class (via the T4 template generation) and `ProductId` for the column (somehow via the *Generate Database from Model...* context menu entry from the diagram), and then use the code-based fluent configuration capabilities to map the two via `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>.HasColumnName()`.

Can I do this or is there a reasonable alternative? I realize I can do this all in code using 4.1, but wondering if this "transitional" approach is possible.

Comment: Good question - its easy enough to do when the schema already exists, via mapping, but now I'm curious about doing it this way as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned this in favor of fully code-first, but I think there's a way to do it:

1. In the model, use column names.
2. Generate SQL from the `.edmx`.
3. In the T4 template, read from a mapping file of some kind (e.g. csv) and apply some logic to generate the C# classes as desired and to generate the `HasColumnName` calls.

this *should* work, but involves more effort than I'm willing to give on creating the right template.

Comment: I came across this issue as well.  No idea how to do it.  But I agree with you that code-first is a better way anyway.   But it would still be good to know this.